# Off-Topic, belongs on another site -- Why is Meta the only option?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Start here:  [Direct USB Charging Battery](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/114883/direct-usb-charging-battery)

This is obviously OT on DIY, the best fit would be electronics.

So, Close, Select "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"  and the only option I'm presented with is

"belongs on diy.meta.stackexchange.com
discussion, support, and feature requests for this site"

My guess is that the belongs on another site option is to recommend a mod migrate the question.  But Meta is not where it should end up.

Comment: Moderators can arrange for additional sites to be added to that list.  The question is, which sites should be added?

Comment: Well, Electronics, Woodworking and Gardening are obvious fits with DIY

Answer (score 1):

Simplest reason? Migration is often a poor choice. On SO we can directly migrate to Super User and Server Fault, but we also have OT closures for them as well, and those are preferred. Why? Because we don't know if the questions would actually fit into those sites. Here's the [list of migrated DIY questions](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/) (10k+ so I can't see it). Generally, mods are reluctant to migrate unless the owner requests it (or it's blatantly obvious).

Meta is the only natural migration for any site because users often confuse talking about the site with using the site.

If the question isn't on-topic, just vote to close. If it could be asked on another network site, use a custom closure reason (leaves a comment) to point them there. I do this all the time [in this tag on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo). The [Auto Review Comments App](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) can help you write a custom closure reason.